# Help me name this scale

Tags: theory, scales

I have a six-tone scale with the notes A#,B,C,D,D#,G. As far as I'm aware this is not contained in any other well known scale. What should I call it?

Comment: Call it "Fred" .    <-- which is to say you've got a collection of notes on which to base a tune but it's a stretch to claim it's a scale.

Comment: No qualified answer, but this tool helps me a lot with such questions. It is mainly written for guitarists, but it will help with such questions:
http://jguitar.com/
In this example you would use the chord to scale harmonizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These notes are (enharmonically) a subset of the 8-note [major Bebop scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bebop_scale#Bebop_major_scale) with root Eb:

`Eb (F) G (Ab) Bb B C D`

where the notes in parentheses are the ones that you leave out to get your six-note scale.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few guidelines for naming scales:

Well, it's a gapped scale (less than seven notes in the octave). You might call it a hextonic scale.

Most scales are named after the gap between the first and third elements. A# to a C is a diminished third.

Scales are *always* spelled sequentially, so there shouldn't be 2 D's, the second one is an Eb.

So you could call it as Diminished Hextonic.

---

Another approach is to find a chord which fits these notes and just name it for the chord.There's a Cminor chord in there (C, Eb, G), so look at how that's extended. with a major 7th (B), so it's now a Cminor(maj7). Then the A#, which could also be spelled as a Bb, is a minor seventh. So perhaps Cm7(+M7).

---

However, none of these are a standard, well-known scale, so I'd declare what notes it has explicitly. Or if you're writing standard score, just write in all the accidentals as they're used.